# d3js Need a line graph which scales time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, line

I am creating a line graph for a friend and am having trouble getting the "data" line to be drawn to the screen. I am using d3js v4 and have the following code which is not working as requested:

```
    $(scope.container).append($('<svg id="svgimg" width="640" height="350" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></svg>'));
        var mainGroup = d3.select("#svgimg").append("g");
        d3.select("#svgimg").call(d3.zoom().on("zoom",function(){
            mainGroup.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.transform.x+","+d3.event.transform.y+") scale ("+d3.event.transform.k+")" );
        }));


        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
        var svg = $("#svgimg"),
        margin = {top:20,right:20,bottom:20,left:20},
        width = +Number(svg.attr("width")) - margin.left -margin.right,
        height = +Number(svg.attr("height")) - margin.top-margin.bottom,
        g = mainGroup.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
        //console.log(width);
        //console.log(height);
        var n = 2000,
            random = d3.randomNormal(0,.2),
            data = d3.range(n).map(random);

        var x =d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([0,n-1])
            .range([0,width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,100])
            .range([height,0]);
        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d,i){return x(parseTime(d.time));})
            .y(function(d,y){return y(d.distance);});

        g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id","clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height);
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class","axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform","translate(0,"+y(0)+")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class","axis axis--y")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
        g.append("g")
            //.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
            .append("path")
            .datum(scope.data)
            .attr("class","linea");
```

Where scope.container is a div element. The issue is that the data line is not being displayed and if it were, it would be incorrent. scope.data is an array of items with the following fields:
        date, time, distance,stamp

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to actually call the line function for the d attribute:  `.attr("d", line)`

Comment: This solution has added to the DOM, the required elements. The line however is still not visible. Inspecting reveals that the "line" is in the correct "position" and that the data attribute is not empty. A quick "svg.innerHTML=svg.innerHTML" failed also.